# Intentando guardar nuevas palabras dentro de una matriz

Tags: javascript, array, bucles, foreach

Hola chicos tengo problemas tratando de guardar unas palabras dentro de un array, lo que intento hacer es guardar todas las palabras que tengan la J como primer digito, pero me esta sobrescribiendo el array, en el console.log podemos ver que solo me guarda una palabra, mi idea es poder sacar un array junto con los dos nombres JUAN Y JHON.

```
'use strict'

  var array = [];

  var words = ["JHON", "CHARLES","KERLYN","YEAH","JUAN"]

words.forEach((element,index)=>{

    var result = [];

    if(element.lastIndexOf("J")==0){

    result.push(element);

}
console.log(result)
 })
```

[image: resultado de la consola]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor traduce el titulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la declaración de la variable de ***result*** debe estar fuera del ciclo

```
'use strict'

  var array = [];

  var words = ["JHON", "CHARLES","KERLYN","YEAH","JUAN"]

  var result = [];

  words.forEach((element,index)=>{

    if(element.lastIndexOf("J")==0){

      result.push(element);

    }
    console.log(result)
 })
```

Comment: 2 comentarios: las respuestas en la plataforma son en español el idioma oficial y segundo por favor esperemos a que el OP la traduzca

Comment: Gracias Victor, te amo xD

Comment: @CristianAlvarezGonzalez la mejor forma de agradecer (una vez que Victor traduzca su aporte) es marcar la respuesta como aceptada